# Why does bounded function fBounded=f.bind() has the same [[Environment]] reference as an original function f?

Tags: javascript, closures

Even though `g` bounded function is a brand new function (update: function-like exotic object) and was created inside another function (`different`) it makes lookup for variables from `closure` scope as function `original` does.

```js
let y = 'GLOB';
function closure(){
  let x = 'x from closure';
  return function original(){
    console.log(x,'|', y);
  }
}

function different(){
  let x = 'x from different';
  let y = 'I have no access too';
  let initial = closure();
  let g = closure().bind(null);// retain same LE
  console.log(g !== initial); // true
  return g; 
}

let bindDoesntAffectClosure = different();
bindDoesntAffectClosure(); // x from closure | GLOB
```

Comment: bind has nothing to do with closures..  What is your question?

Comment: Bind changes the context (the `this`), it doesn't change the scope (the `x` in this case)

Comment: bind creates a brand new function. I'm just curious why the new function has the same Lexical Environment as a function on which bind method was called. Probably because bind method does not discard the Lexical reference. Put it another way - I wasn't certain weather the very last call will print x from closure or x from different until I run the snippet and saw the result.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4v6n8wud/

Comment: Ok last chance :) how let g = f.bind() is different from let g = function(){}
In both cases we get a new function g. In first case calling bindDoesntAffectClosure will lookup for x variable inside closure block(will have [[Environment]] link to closure() Lexical Environment) In second case get value for x from different block.

Comment: @daGo `bind` doesn't create a new function with a new body in a different scope, it creates a small wrapper function that calls the original function and nothing else. `g = f.bind(c)` is equivalent to `g = (...args) => f.call(c, ...args)`.

Answer (score 0):

According to MDN: If we have `f` function then calling `f.bind(someObject)` creates a new function with the **same** body and **scope** as `f`.
So it doesn't matter *where* new bounded function was created - it always will has a reference to the scope where `f` was declared.